# Cannot boot into osx after partitioning in macos

Tags: startup, partition, unix, high-sierra, recovery-hd

So I have Ubuntu and high sierra working fine, but yesterday I decided to expand the ubuntu disk space. So I free up space in the macos by deleting application and then doing a partition(this is how I remember allocating space for ubuntu when I installed it). The partition was done in osx. After a reboot, the option to boot osx is gone, so I can only boot ubuntu with reFind. I'm guessing the macos might have unmounted it self after the partitioning or it might have to do with the new mac file system which reFind doesn't recognise.

Booting into recovery with command-R all I get is internet recovery and error code of -2002F meaning I cannot connect to apple server.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I need more information about your partition tables. Please do the following.

Boot to Ubuntu.

Use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key to open a Terminal window.

Enter the commands shown below.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
```

The `gdisk` command is interactive. Enter the <kbd>P</kbd> key followed by the <kbd>Q</kbd> key.

Post the output from these two commands to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help David, I ended up doing a full recovery.